# Группировка по двум полям и максимальному значению

Tags: mysql, выборка, запрос

Добрый день.

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT sg_city.name AS news_city_name, newsblock . * , DATE_FORMAT( create_date, '%d.%m.%Y' ) AS date_news, count( comments.rzd ) AS comments_count
FROM `newsblock`
LEFT JOIN sg_city ON (newsblock.city = sg_city.id )
LEFT JOIN comments ON ( comments.post_id = newsblock.id AND comments.rzd = 'news' )
WHERE newsblock.moder =1
AND create_date <= now()
GROUP BY newsblock.head
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

Выводит список всех новостей, но в этом списке есть поле "newsblock_game", в котором указывается id из другой таблицы для некоторых новостей. Суть в том, что нужно не просто выводить все новости подряд, а ещё и группировать те, что имеют одинаковый "newsblock_game" и отличный от нуля, при этом выводиться должна последняя из них.

Пробовал оперировать с `MAX()`, но ничего не получилось: либо не группируется, либо тупо сцепляет все новости до нескольких штук.

Не хотелось бы подзапрос использовать, думал, может, есть какие-то варианты...

Для наглядности:

```
id | head | game | create_date
1 | заголовок 1 | 0 | 2014-10-12
2 | заголовок 2 | 0 | 2014-10-13
3 | заголовок 3 | 55 | 2014-10-14
4 | заголовок 4 | 55 | 2014-10-15
5 | заголовок 5 | 0 | 2014-10-15
```

---

Нужно, чтобы в выборке было:

1. заголовок 1
2. заголовок 2
3. заголовок 4
4. заголовок 5

**Обновление**

Запрос выводит все заголовки новостей с постраничным видом, но появился новый вид новостей "репортажи с места событий". Репортажи состоят из нескольких новостей с одинаковым значением поля "game", у простых новостей он равен нулю. Вот и нужно, чтобы в ленте новостей они тоже отображались, но не все подрят, а только последний актуальный по дате с конкретным значением поля "game".

Comment: @insk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вам сначала надо получить `id` новостей, которые вас интересуют, а получив этот список еще раз соединиться с новостями по этим `id` (ну или используя `in`, что в принципе одно и то же).

```
select * from newsblock n
join (select max(id) as id from newsblock where game <> 0 group by game
      union all
      select id from newsblock where game=0) nb on n.id = nb.id
```

Дальше уже к этому запросу цепляйте остальные `join`'ы...

Answer (score 0):

Приведи лучше изначальные таблицы - вообще слабо понял, что надо тебе. (

Из того, что понял - тебе подойдет, наверное, конструкция UNION:

```
Select

//тут тащим только то что  newsblock_game=0 и группируем как нада
UNION
SELECT 
//тут тащим только то что  newsblock_game!=0 и делаем свою группировку

И сортируем все ето по дате
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос.